# Display image in Java GUI using component other than JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I am new to Java GUI programming. I am working on an application where I need to display images, on a UI along with some other button/controls. I have a working piece of code which uses JFrame.

My requirement is where I want to add some more widgets such as button to start/stop displaying image etc. When I am using Jframe to display image, it occupies the entire JFrame, and I can't add other controls.

I am looking for something that I can display image and add it as a component in to JFrame. Can someone explain how this can be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am new to Java GUI programming. I am working on an application where I need to display images, on a UI along with some other button/controls. I have a working piece of code which uses JFrame.

As a general bit of un-asked for advice, I will recommend that you try to avoid having your classes extend top-level window classes such as JFrame as this will limit greatly what you can do with the class. Better if you need to extend a Swing component that it be a JPanel, as this can be placed in a JFrame, a JDialog, a JOptionPane, another JPanel,... pretty much anywhere in your GUI. Note that most of the time you won't even need to have your class extend a component.

> My requirement is where I want to add some more widgets such as button to start/stop displaying image etc. When I am using Jframe to display image, it occupies the entire JFrame, and I can't add other controls.

This is a bit confusing as a JFrame does not by itself have a mechanism to display an image.

> I am looking for something that I can display image and add it as a component in to JFrame. Can someone explain how this can be done?

Your requirements are a bit vague, but consider:

- Make ImageIcons for each image that you wish to display, and save your icons.
- Create a single JLabel for displaying images.
- Call `setIcon(someIcon)` on your JLabel to swap images.
- If your image needs to change size to fit the component that's displaying it, then have your display component extend JPanel, and display your image in the JPanel's `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method, as per Kevin Workman's answer (1+ to it!).

If this information doesn't help you, then please consider fleshing out your question a bit more by providing us with more relevant background information and relevant code.

Answer (score 4):

One easy way is to display the image in a `JLabel`.

### ImageViewer

[image: Many (OK 3) images]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.util.Random;

public class ImageViewer {
    
    JPanel gui;
    /** Displays the image. */
    JLabel imageCanvas;

    /** Set the image as icon of the image canvas (display it). */
    public void setImage(Image image) {
        imageCanvas.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
    }
    
    public void initComponents() {
        if (gui==null) { 
            gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
            imageCanvas = new JLabel();
            
            JPanel imageCenter = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            imageCenter.add(imageCanvas);
            JScrollPane imageScroll = new JScrollPane(imageCenter);
            imageScroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,100));
            gui.add(imageScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
    }
    
    public Container getGui() {
        initComponents();
        return gui;
    }
    
    public static Image getRandomImage(Random random) {
        int w = 100 + random.nextInt(400);
        int h = 50 + random.nextInt(200);
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                w,h,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        
        return bi;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Image Viewer");
                // TODO Fix kludge to kill the Timer
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            
                final ImageViewer viewer = new ImageViewer();
                f.setContentPane(viewer.getGui());
                
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                f.setVisible(true);

                ActionListener animate = new ActionListener() {

                    Random random = new Random();
                    
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        viewer.setImage(getRandomImage(random));
                    }
                };
                Timer timer = new Timer(1500,animate);
                timer.start();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several components that support displaying icon. One of them is JLabel: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html

Another option is to extend JPanel and override the paintComponent() method to display whatever you want, including images: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/